# Restoring OAuth 2.0 Client ID for game

Tags: google-play, google-play-games, google-api-client, google-play-console, google-console-developer

When reporting achievements and leader boards I got an error 401, login required.
I have a game in Google Play which use Google Play Games Services. When I go to Game services tab and choose my game I go to "Linked apps" section, select my game. At the bottom there is a OAuth2 Client ID
for example

`123456789012-randomlettersandnumbers.apps.googleusercontent.com`

and than in console.developers.google.com under Credinentials tab above Client ID is missing.
I have other one for example:

`123456789012-reallydifferentrandomstring.apps.googleusercontent.com`

Is it possible to restore first ClientID? Because I think this is a cause of 401 error.

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out. To restore/use valid Client ID I need to link game again in Game Services. But there is one thing to fix on Firebase. In firebase console I have to download google-services.json (and add to game) again because Client ID change here as well.